# How to validate an integer user input with minimum length 1 and maximum length 32 using robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, numeric, alphanumeric

How to validate an integer user input with minimum length 1 and maximum length 32 using robot framework ?

```html
<input type="number"/
```

Length should be 1 to 32 inclusive.

Thank you!

Comment: show your trials and errors and code examples, read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use BuiltIn library:

```
Validate Length Should Be True
   ${length} =  Get Length    ${result}         #Here we get length of your input
   Log    ${length}                             #Here we can check what is the length (it is not necessary)
   ${status} =  Evaluate  0 < ${length} < 33    #Here we evaluate that input is more than 0 and less that 33 and get status (True or False)
   Should Be True    ${status}                  #Here we validate that status should be true. If number is between 1-32 inclusive test will pass

*** Variables ***
${result} =   1123423452346   #Here you can paste your input
```

let me know if it helped, if not, I will think about another solution :)

Comment: The answers seems okay, but please try to explain or provide details outside the code snippet. As it is right now, it is difficult for people who are using small screens to read the comments.

Comment: I got this error "No keyword with name 'Validate Length Should Be True' found."

Comment: No keyword with name 'Validate' found. Did you mean:
    BuiltIn.Evaluate

Comment: Here is documentation about keywords from BuiltIn Library Get Length: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Length         
Evaluate: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate      
Should Be True: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20True

Comment: @AbhishekK
'Validate Length Should Be True' Is just my name of this keyword you can name it what you want and then use this keyword in your   ***Test Cases***  :)